# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unexpected token "punctuation"

Tags: php, twig

I have try to converted my php code to Twig code.

Php code:

```
<?php foreach ($languages as $language) { 
    if(empty($my_title[$language["language_id"]])){$my_title[$language["language_id"]] ="MY Title";}
?>
```

to Twig:

```
{% for language in languages %}
    {% if not my_title[language.language_id] %}
      {% set my_title[language.language_id] = "MY Title" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but, Does get following error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message
>   'Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "[" ("end of statement block"
>   expected) in....

what do wrong here? how to write properly this code in twig?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add items to arrays or hashes in Twig directly. You need to use `merge` filter, like this:

```
{% set my_title = my_title|merge({(language.language_id): 'MY Title'}) %}
```

Notice the parenthesis around `language.language_id`. That's because a hash key cannot be an expression but a literal. Parenthesis around `language.language_id` make sure that the expression is evaluated before being used as the hash key.

In addition, your `if` statement will fail if `my_title` hash does not have the key stored in `language.language_id` variable. You should use `is defined` test there.

Complete example:

```
{% for language in languages %}
    {% if not my_title[language.language_id] %}
        {% set my_title = my_title|merge({(language.language_id): 'MY Title'}) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks. working fine in my code. just, minor changes in code. I have update code.

Comment: I have try for description. but, Does not get value. I have try something like. any suggestion please. `{% if not my_description[language.language_id].description %}
 {% set my_description = my_description|merge({ (language.language_id).description : 'My Description'}) %}
 {% endif %}`  **php code have:** `<?php foreach ($languages as $language) { 
    if(empty($my_description[$language["language_id"]]['description'])){$my_description[$language["language_id"]]['description'] ="MY Description";}
?>`

Comment: You need to wrap the entire `language.language_id.description` in parenthesis, not just `language.language_id`, like this: `{% set my_description = my_description|merge({ (language.language_id.description): 'My Description'}) %}`

Comment: Oh, I think I figured it out. Does this work for you: `{% set my_description = my_description|merge({ (language.language_id): {'description': 'My Description'}}) %}` ?